# Jinja prints huge whitespace in browser before output even though output prints properly in terminal

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

My code prints a big whitespace in my jinja html output. And then after that prints the required results. I am performing a simple `select` statement and would like to display it. I would like to avoid (and understand why it happens) the whitespace in my html output.

`app.py`

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template
import psycopg2
import os
import sqlalchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(12)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://user:pw@localhost/db')
    result = engine.execute('select * from person.personphone limit 10;') # adventureworks db
    col_names = result.keys()
    col_vals = [dict(row) for row in result]
    ######################################### used for debugging
    for col in col_names:
        print(col, end=' ')
    print('')
    for row in col_vals:
        for col in col_names:
            print(row[col], end=' ')
        print('')
    ######################################### end debugging

    return render_template('home.html', colname=col_names, colval=col_vals)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`home.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

Hello world

<br>

<div id="table">
    <table>
        <tr>
        {% for col in colname %}
            <th>{{ col }} </th>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        <br>
        {% for row in colval %}
            <tr>
            {% for col in colname %}
                <td>{{ row[col] }} </td>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            <br>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Terminal output:

[image]

Jinja output on browser:

[image]

Comment: What's your markup like? What does it show when you view source in the browser? Can this be a CSS issue?

Comment: @dmitrybelyakov View page source does not give any info for the blank space. It shows the data properly. CSS - Bootstrap. I removed it, yet I see the same issue.

Comment: Oh and by the way, try getting rid of `<br>` tags inside your table markup. They shouldn't be there. Yes that's your issue. I'll move it to a proper answer.

Comment: Removing the `<br>` helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `<br>` tags in between your table rows that get printed above the table. Remove them - they shouldn't be there:

```
<div id="table">
    <table>
        <tr>
        {% for col in colname %}
            <th>{{ col }} </th>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% for row in colval %}
            <tr>
            {% for col in colname %}
                <td>{{ row[col] }} </td>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok that helped. But I want to understand why this happens. Like, does the code not run first, **then** render template? If I have the breaks, then it shows that it is still going through the loop, so why is it not finding the data if the `<br>` works to print the whitespace?

Comment: The code is fine and it has nothing to do with Jinja - this is simply invalid html markup and that's how a browser will render it. You can try it out yourself with just a standalone html page.